# How to enable Single Logout in onelogin

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml, onelogin

I have a spring boot application that uses an oauth2 spring boot application for authentication. I was able to enable the SAML into the Oauth2 application and point it against the ONELOGIN developer portal and successfully do authentications. But when I logout from the application it is not actually logging me out of the ONELOGIN. When I trigger the app logout it redirects to the ONELOGIN login page and then I am logged back into the application.

I am trying to achieve the single logout here, I just want to get my application logged out of the ONELOGIN.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler. This is called a Relying Provider (RP) logout, to make searching for results easier. Note that this is usually not what you want, unless your OIDC session is a 1 to 1 relationship, or a few other cases.

```
OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() { 
  OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler successHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
  successHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/"));
        return successHandler;
}
```

Then, you need to modify your existing logout in the overridden `configure`   method for the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to include:

```
.and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
```

That will then log you out of the OIDC provider as well as the client app.

Comment: I don't think this relevant here since he is using SAML. I do see your point of using OneLogin SDK. Using SDK we should be able to kill user's session.